# SimpleBlobDetector filtering by area

Tags: opencv

I want to detect some blobs but only of certain size - between min and max area.
When I set the params like this:

```
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.filterByInertia = false;
params.filterByConvexity = false;
params.filterByColor = true;
params.blobColor = 0; //filter only black 
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 10.0f;
params.maxArea = 20.0f; //I want the diameter of blob to be between those values
```

and check the keypoint.size value of each blob detected as a result, I see that there're blobs of very small size (less than 10) detected. And the big blobs I want to get (with diamteter between the min/max area) are ignored. Why is that so, considering the filter by area is applied? Is my understanding of filtering by area wrong, or is the params setting wrong somehow?
Do I need to process the image somehow before I call detect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params.minArea` and `params.maxArea` filters blobs by **area** and if I recall correctly, you are currently searching for blobs that have area between 10 and 20 pixels (note that this is quite small for standard 480p frames).

If you want to filter by **diameter**, use this (assuming the blobs are circles):

```
params.minArea = 3.14159 * 5.0f * 5.0f; // Min 10.0f diameter
params.minArea = 3.14159 * 10.0f * 10.0f; // Max 20.0f diameter
```